# How do I put a variable into a FOR /F cmd in a batch file?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

This will output files with the given mask:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir C:\temp\*Gold* /b') DO (something)
```

This will work as well:

```
set DOScmd='dir C:\temp\*Gold* /b'
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN (!DOScmd!) DO (something)
```

But if I make it a variable:`suffix`, it FAILS with `File Not Found`? :

```
set suffix=*Gold*
set DOScmd='dir C:\temp\'!suffix!' /b'
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN (!DOScmd!) DO (something)
```

and this fails too:

```
set suffix=*Gold*
set DOScmd='dir C:\temp\'%suffix%' /b'
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN (!DOScmd!) DO (something)
```

Comment: If you've solved your own question, please post it as an answer and mark it as accepted. (That's totally fine here.)

Comment: DOS has no `FOR /f` at all. It has no delayed expansion either so `!var!` like that doesn't work. If you're talking about the Windows cmd then it's a completely different beast

Comment: The single-quotes or apostrophes `'` are specific to `for /F`, and it is expected to enclose the command in between a pair os such. The `dir` command does not particularly handle them, so in `dir C:\temp\'!suffix!' /b` they are treated just as literal characters, so remove them around `!suffix!` and everything will work fine. Anyway, I'd exclude them from variable `DOScmd` and place them here: `… in ('!DOScmd!') do …`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: (just leave the quotes in the loop)

```
set suffix=*Gold*
set DOScmd=dir C:\temp\!suffix! /b
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('!DOScmd!') DO (something)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think for that case you need to wrap the suffix variable in % when setting it into DOScmd since its outside of parenthesis

```
set suffix=*Gold*
set DOScmd='dir C:\temp\'%suffix%' /b'
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%g in (!DOScmd!) DO (something)
```